# Search results template, modal viewing of video items

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, html, display-template

How to create a pop up dialog box with details, when I click an event in a Content Search Web Part in Sharepoint 2013 in the case of video item.

```
_#-->
        <div class="ms-srch-video-intent ms-srch-video-intent-container" id="_#= containerId =#_" data-displaytemplate="VideoIntentItem">
            <div class="ms-srch-video-results-centered ms-srch-video-intent">
                <a clicktype="Result" href="_#= linkUrl =#_" title="_#= $htmlEncode(line1.value) =#_" id="_#= pathId =#_">
                    _#= imageMarkup =#_
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="ms-srch-video-intent-data">
                <h3>
                    <a clicktype="Result" href="_#= linkUrl =#_" title="_#= $htmlEncode(line1.value) =#_" class="ms-srch-video-intent ms-srch-video-results ms-srch-item-link ms-noWrap" id="_#= line1Id =#_">
                        _#= line1 =#_
                    </a>
                </h3>
<!--#_
```

Answer (score 0):

To open a item with a modal dialog, i think that if i remember it correctly you will need to add the bold line in the display templates script tag. (I'm not sure if this is applicable for the video item display template.)

**EnsureScriptFunc("sp.ui.dialog.js", "SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog", null);**

So it looks like this:

```
 <script>
        $includeLanguageScript(this.url, "~sitecollection/_catalogs/masterpage/Display Templates/Language Files/{Locale}/CustomStrings.js");
        EnsureScriptFunc("sp.ui.dialog.js", "SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog", null);
    </script>
```

and then add this to Line1.

```
 <a onclick="javascript:SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog({ url: '_#= linkURL =#_', title: '_#= $htmlEncode(line1.defaultValueRenderer(line1)) =#_' }); return false;" onmouseover="javascript:this.style.cursor='pointer';">
```

[How to create a pop up dialog box with details, when I click an event in a Content Search Web Part in Sharepoint 2013](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/145656/how-to-create-a-pop-up-dialog-box-with-details-when-i-click-an-event-in-a-conte)

[Showing Modal Dialog in Content By Search Result Item](http://softlanding.ca/blog/showing-modal-dialog-in-content-by-search-result-item)